# What is difference between std::stof and atof when each one should be used?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read some documents about each, for example

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

I understand that `atof` is part of `<cstdlib>` and has `const char*` as input parameter, and `std::stof` is part of `<string>` and has different input format.

But it's not clear,

- can they be used interchangeably:
- do they convert to same `float` value with same input?
- what scenario is best to use for each of these?

Comment: To begin with [`std::atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) doesn't have any kind of validation or error checking. It can return undefined values (have *undefined behavior*).

Answer (score 12):

I assume you meant to compare [`std::atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) with [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (both return `double`).

Just comparing the two linked reference pages yields the following differences :

- `std::atof` takes a `char*`, while `std::stod` takes either a `std::string` or a `std::wstring` (ie. it has support for wide strings)
- `std::stod` will also return the index of the first unconverted character if the `pos` parameter is not `NULL` (useful for further parsing of the string)
- if the converted value falls outside of the range of a `double`, `std::atof` will return an undefined value, while `std::stod` will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception (definitely better than an undefined value)
- if no conversion can be performed, `std::atof` will return `0.0`, while `std::stod` will throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception (easier to distinguish with an *actual* converted `0.0`)

These are all positive points for `std::stod`, making it the more advanced alternative of the 2.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you have a c-style string (`char*`) then `std::atof` has less overhead than std:stod since it does not have to create an `std::string`.  This means `std::atof` could be used if (and only if) you need to optimize your code.  This should be a **LAST RESORT**.

Comment: @Nathan if you want performance use [from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)

Answer (score 3):

Everything Sander said is correct.  However, you specifically asked:

**Can they be used interchangeably?**

The answer is no, at least not in the general case.  If you're using atof, chances are good that you have legacy C code.  In that case, you must be careful about introducing code that can throw exceptions, especially in "routine" situations such as when a user gives bad input.

**Do they convert to same `float` value with same input?**

No.  They both convert to a `double` value, not a float.  Conversion to the same value isn't specifically guaranteed by the standard (to my knowledge), and it is possible that there is round-off somewhere that is slightly different.  However, given valid input, I would be pretty surprised if there were a difference between the return values from the two in the same compiler.

**What scenario is best to use for each of these?**

If:

- You have a conforming C++ 11 or later compiler, and
- Your code can tolerate exceptions (or you're willing to catch them around every call), and
- You already have a std::string or the performance hit of a conversion is unimportant.
- Or, if you are a C++ beginner and don't know the answers to these questions.

Then I would suggest using std::stod.  Otherwise, you could consider using atof.